# Arithmetic Sum of Characters

Tags: string, math, character

For a homework assignment I have been told that the arithmetic sum of the following characters is equal to 837. 'E', '-', '0', '5', '-', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o',

Can someone explain how?

Thanks

Comment: The sum of the ASCII values maybe?

Comment: The sum of ASCII values is 792 according to `printf("sum: %d", 'E' + '-' + '0' + '5' + '-' + 'h' + 'e' + 'l' + 'l' + 'o');`

Comment: yup sum of ASCII is 792.. surely it's the ASCII value and we're missing info from OP

Comment: It's missing a `-`which has code 45 to make it 837. Probably a typo then.

Comment: What a ridiculous assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the decimal value of each character [here](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aASCII-Table-wide.svg). Assuming you are missing an 'a' from your list of characters, the sum of the decimal values for the ASCII encoding is 837.